# How to compile assembly files using vs2008?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, assembly

I use vs2008 . and need to compile project that include ".asm" files.

how I can do that?

Comment: Which part of this question is C++?

Comment: the project is "C++" but it include ".asm" files

Answer (score 2):

Right-click the project in the Solution Explorer window, Custom Build Rules, tick "Microsoft Macro Assembler".  This ensures that any .asm files you add to your project get compiled with the custom build rule for .asm files.

If you still have problems, *do* make sure you document the error message you see.  They are meant to be helpful.

Comment: Do you need to install MASM separately or is it included with VS?

Comment: @Ferr - depends on the edition, I think, fairly sure it isn't included with the Express edition.  Look for vc/bin/ml.exe in the VS install directory.  It is a free download.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your helpful answer .. now when compile my code the following error appear : "error A2070: invalid instruction operands" at this line  movss   xmm0, xi

Comment: @user - great, your problem is solved.  Now you got another one, you didn't document it properly either.  My crystal ball is worn out, I'm going to have to buy a new one.  Start a new question.

Answer (score 1):

The basic question is more or less answered, but what if you want to do just assembly language in your Visual Studio project? Here is the answer:

- Start with a General - Empty project.
- Right-clicking on the project name in the solution explorer, set
  Custom Build Rules so that the Microsoft Macro Assembler is used.
- Next, go to Project - Properties. Find the Linker in the dialog box
  and expand it (click on the +).
- Under the Linker, select System.
- On the top line, Subsystem, click the down arrow and choose "Console
  (/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE)."
- In the same dialog box under Linker, select Advanced.
- Edit the top line, Entry Point, so that it is the label you used as
  the starting point of your code. Note: You should not enter the
  underscore when filling in the Entry Point. VS apparently adds an
  underscore.

Your environment is now set to do assembly langauge programming as a project.

The procedure works also in Microsoft's free Visual C++ 2008 Express edition which is still downloadable from MS as of the date of this posting.

Good luck and have fun!

Comment: Is it really necessary to set SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE subsytem and why?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make use of [MASM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/afzk3475%28v=VS.90%29.aspx).
MASM stands for Microsoft Macro Assembler Reference.

Another more straightforward and easier way of accomplishing asm in VS is [inlining](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ks26t93%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) your asm code into your C/C++ source files.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. I can build this project using "Win32"..but when use MFC ..I can't

Comment: It is important where exactly you stick that assembly code since things can go wrong pretty easily, esp. when using MFC. Being more specific and some build errors will definitely help in nailing it down.